# Delete script via modified date and filename

Tags: shell-script, scripting, delete

I am currently creating a script that deletes files that are more than 7 days.
This is my current script.

```
find -type f -mtime +6 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

I need to include a name pattern, so it deletes only those with `LOGS` in the filename.
Sample files:

- AppA.txt
- AppB.txt
- AppA_LOGS.txt
- AppB_LOGS.txt

It will only delete the `AppA_LOGS.txt` and `AppB_LOGS.txt` files (assuming they are older 7 days) and `App.txt` and `AppB.txt` will remain even they are more than 7 days old.

How can I add it in my current script? Thank you.

Comment: `find -name "*LOGS*" -type f -mtime +6 -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Answer (score 2):

To filter by name use the `-name` predicate which takes a wildcard pattern similar to those used in shell globbing:

```
find . -name '*_LOGS.txt' -type f -mtime +6 -exec rm -f {} +
```

It's better to put that filter first, as it's generally less expensive than the ones that are based on file metadata (though some `find` implementations do that reordering automatically). That way, if a file is excluded because its name doesn't end in `_LOGS.txt`, `find` doesn't need to retrieve its metadata.

Like in shell globs, `*` matches any sequence of characters. Note that contrary to shell globs, there is no special handling of files whose name starts with `.` (hidden files), so they will be included as well. Same for files in directories whose name starts with `.`.

Also note that `rm` can take more than one filename as argument, so you can use `+` instead of `;` as the `-exec` delimiter. That also has the advantage of `find` reporting errors by `rm` in its exit code.

Also note that portably, you need to give at least one file or directory as argument to `find` for it to know where to search. Some `find` implementations default to `.` (the current working directory) when you don't tell it where to look, but some others don't.

If using `zsh`, you could also just do:

```
rm -f -- **/*_LOGS.txt(D.m+6)
```

Where `.` is the equivalent of `-type f`, `m+6` of `-mtime +6` and `D` also considers hidden files and files in hidden dirs like `find` does.

Contrary to some `find` implementations, it will still manage to remove files whose name contains sequence of bytes not forming valid characters in the locale. It could however fail to execute `rm` if there is a very large list of files to remove (but see the `zargs` function or the `zsh/files` module to make `rm` builtin to work around that).

Comment: one question please, in zsh the order of these `D.m+6` matter?

Comment: @αғsнιη, not for those. It would matter for `-` (what follows applies after symlink resolution) or `^` (negation) `,` (or)... In terms of perf, I suppose order  could matter if there are qualifiers that use different sources of information for the files (lstat, stat, directory contents (F)...), never really looked into it much.